# Slide from right to left animation using css

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

currently I write code to display a hidden div using `jQuery`. But I want to make an animation effect for this div when it appearing in the window . 
  When I click on the window2 then window2 is appearing without an animation . How can I make window2 coming as a slide from left to right or right to left?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <style>

      .row{
          margin-top:10%;
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 327px) and (min-width:318px)
            { 
                .window2{
                    display:none;
                    width:20%;
                }
                #next{
                    background-color: black;
                    width:100%;
                    border:2px solid black;
                    color:white;
                    cursor:pointer;
                }
            }

  </style>


 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 window1">
          <div style="width:80%;height:50%;border:1px solid black;">
              Hiii

          </div>
          <span id="next" class="visible-xs"> window2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-10  window2">

          <div style="height:50%;border:1px solid black;">
              Hello

          </div>


      </div>
  </div>
 </div>    
  <script>
      $("#next").on("click",function(){

         $(".window2").css("display","block"); 
         $(".window2").css("margin-top","-82%"); 
         $(".window2").css("left","80%"); 

      });

 </script>
```

Please help . I tried

```
.window2{
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease .15s;
    transition: all .3s ease .15s;
}
```

But nothing change .

Thank you .

Comment: can you create a fiddle please

Comment: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ the best for css animations and really easy to use

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS with jQuery to create this effect.

This is the code:

```js
  $("#next").on("click", function() {

    $(".slideRightToLeft").addClass('show');
  });
```

```css
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    font-family: verdana;
  }
  
  #next {
    background-color: #1BAA95;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .slideRightToLeft {
    background-color: #164656;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  
  .slideRightToLeft.show {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='next'> Next
</div>

<div class='slideRightToLeft'>
  Right to Left
</div>
```

and this is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fy4qwrem/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.animate()` from `jQuery`

```
$("#window2").animate({ // id of your animated object
  display: block,
  margin-top: "-82%",
  left: "80%"
}, 1000); // time animation should take
```

For more information on `.animate()` see the jQuery documentation: [Link](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)